# Transpose multiple records with awk

Tags: php, bash, awk

I'm trying to transpose the output from my torrent program Deluge to something I can put into columns in a php-file.

The output from *deluge-console info* looks like this (example):

```
Name: 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip
ID: ebd9f05d220e7afd62fcbb10743bf9210a59efd5
State: Seeding Up Speed: 0.0 KiB/s
Seeds: 0 (10) Peers: 0 (0) Availability: 0.00
Size: 780.0 MiB/780.0 MiB Ratio: 17.988
Seed time: 10 days 16:29:52 Active: 10 days 17:44:08
Tracker status: raspberrypi.org: Announce OK

Name: ArchLinuxARM-2014.01-rpi.img.zip
ID: d8b3fb8bf7064108d26390d8a3ec586b70182e18
State: Seeding Up Speed: 0.0 KiB/s
Seeds: 0 (3) Peers: 0 (0) Availability: 0.00
Size: 182.7 MiB/182.7 MiB Ratio: 8.222
Seed time: 10 days 16:05:32 Active: 10 days 16:49:27
Tracker status: raspberrypi.org: Announce OK
```

How can I use awk to get something like this:

```
Name                            State    Ratio   Size
2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian....  Seeding  17.988  780.0 MB
ArchLinuxARM-2014.01-rpi.im...  Seeding   8.222  182.7 MB
```

I know that I have to use the different input and output variables to make this happen, but being a newbie in awk, I was hoping for at little starter help.

Console looks like this when running the command: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e34da2a

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F ': *| +' '$1 ~ /Name|Size|State/{a[$1]=$2}
   NF > 1 && $(NF-1) ~ /Ratio/{
     printf "%-40s %-15s %10s %10s MB\n", a["Name"], a["State"], $NF, a["Size"];
     delete a; next}' file

2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip           Seeding             17.988      780.0 MB
ArchLinuxARM-2014.01-rpi.img.zip         Seeding              8.222      182.7 MB
```

Comment: How does the "file" variable function in this code?

Comment: file is is the name of input file here,so just replace this with your actual log file name.

Comment: Ah, there is no log file output per se, only the result of a terminal command. I've put a screenshot of the result of the command in my original post for reference.

Comment: In that case just pipe and awk command as: **`your-command |  awk -F ': *| +' '$1 ~ /Name|Size|State/{a[$1]=$2} NF > 1 && $(NF-1) ~ /Ratio/{printf "%-40s %-15s %10s %10s MB\n", a["Name"], a["State"], $NF, a["Size"]; delete a; next}'`**

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want using php itself?

```
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>Ratio</td>
    <td>Size</td>
</tr>
<?php
$output=array();
exec("FULL_PATH_TO_DELUGE_CONSOLE/deluge-console info",$output);
$raw=explode("\n", $output);
foreach ($raw as $row)
{
    $resultset=explode(' ',$row);
    switch ($resultset[0])
    {
        case 'Name:':
            $name=$resultset[1];
            break;
        case 'State:':
            $state=$resultset[1];
            break;
        case 'Size:':
            $size=$resultset[1];
            $ratio=$resultset[5];
            echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$state.'</td><td>'.$ratio.'</td><td>'.$size.'</td></tr>';
            break;
    }
}
?>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I have very little experience with php, I was hoping to use only awk and implement the code in a copy of the other modules already in the project.

This might help, though. Do I only have to add `<?php` at the top of this text to make it a functional php-file?

Comment: I add some code. Now you can simply copy this code into empty .php. Don't forget change FULL_PATH_TO_FILE to full path to torrent's output file.

Comment: Ah, there isn't an output file per se, only a command that I can run to get that info. I have included an image in my original post for clarification.
I have looked in the other module-php-files in the project, and it seems that many of them are setting variables that are exec() of a bash command.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm2kz05jnrdx3f7/deluge-console.png   This webpage is not available

Comment: _only a command that I can run to get that info._ Use redirect  '**command 1>outputfile**'

Comment: Sorry about that, I have uploaded it in another place: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e34da2a

Comment: I want to run the awk command in directly in the php so I didn't have to run `deluge-console info > foo` everytime the site will reload.

For details, see the files in the /sh/ in this [GitHub-repo](https://github.com/afaqurk/linux-dash).

Comment: See updated post. **$output=array();exec("FULL_PATH_TO_DELUGE_CONSOLE/deluge-console info",$output);$raw=explode("\n", $output);**

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
deluge-console info|awk '$1=="Name:" {name=$2} $1=="State:" {state=$2} $1=="Size:" {print name,state,$6,$2}' >output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $2, $6, $24, $20, "MB"}' file
2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip Seeding 17.988 780.0 MB
ArchLinuxARM-2014.01-rpi.img.zip Seeding 8.222 182.7 MB
```

Use printf instead of print to format as you like.